# TextBox Date Validation

Tags: c#, winforms, date, textbox, cultureinfo

I am using the following code for Short date validation.

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("fr-FR");
if (DateTime.TryParse(textBox1.Text, out dt))
{ textBox1.Text = dt.ToShortDateString(); }
```

But there is a small Problem, If user enters 1/1/1 the output looks like 01/01/2001.

if user enter 1-1-1 the output looks like 01/01/2001. Because of Format given by me.

now what i want if user enter like 1-1-1 the output should be 01-01-2001.

Comment: Try to use maked textbox.... Its a better option....

Comment: No matter what format user enters the date -> after the string is parsed to DateTime -> it's displayed always the same way. Because it's the same DateTime value -> only the input was different.

Comment: @sree aneev so you want to get the output according to input right? means if you enters 1/1/1 you want 01/01/2001 and if user enters 1-1-1 you want 01-01-2001. is that so???

Comment: @kashif right i want like that is there any chance...

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
dt.ToString(@"dd-MM-yyyy");
```

And if you want to diferentiate the output according to the input, I would suggest this:

```
if (textbox1.Text.Contains("/"))
{
    textBox1.Text = dt.ToString(@"dd/MM/yyyy");
}
else
{
    textBox1.Text = dt.ToString(@"dd-MM-yyyy");
}
```

Comment: for this 1/1/1 what can i do i want both as per the user

Comment: @Matus It is me who upvoted you for your answer. But as opposed to this I ask the questioner why doesn't he use MaskTextBox. If I were him, I would never use TextBox for Date purpose atleast.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you are using TextBox instead of [MaskedTextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kkx4h3az.aspx) in such condition. 
I would recommend you use MaskedTExtBox for this. Drag and Drop two MaskedTextBox from ToolBox to your Form and in the FormLoadEvent use this code

```
maskedTextBox1.Mask = "##/##/####";
maskedTextBox2.Mask = "##-##-####";
```

Comment: Note: I have used Two MaskedBoxes to show you that you can use any type of your desired format. you can even set it manual according to you requirement.

Comment: but he wants to format the date in two different ways according to the user input in the same textbox

Comment: just try one thing @kashif if he enter 1/1/1 what should be the answer for your first "##/##/####" for the above one the answer should be 1//1//1. it is wrong.